# DataGridview doesn't show data on different computer

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, datagridview

I created a small SQLite DB based application. It uses 3 grids that bind to a BindingList<> to display the data from objects.

The databinding is generated like this:

```
skillDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
skillDataGridView.DataSource = (BindingList<ISkill>)character.Skills;
skillDataGridView.Columns["skillvalue"].ReadOnly = false;
```

with

```
public interface ISkill : INotifyPropertyChanged, IModifyableValueItem, IXPCostingItem, IDBItem
{
    string Attribute { get; }
}

public interface IModifyableValueItem
{
    string Name { get; }
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IXPCostingItem
{
    int ExperienceCost { get; }
}
```

This works on my computer - flawlessly. Now I created a release build. This also works on my computer, but if my friend runs this on his computer, it adds rows to the grid views, but they contain no data as if the databinding did not work. How can this happen?

Comment: where's the DB file located at?

Comment: the db is found. It fills other gridviews and that works fine. Just the grids based on the binding-lists are not working.

Comment: if datagridview generate rows, maybe your DataSource(BindingList) have only empty strings on null?

Comment: but why then does the same action work on one pc but not the other? And still, it should display the numerical properties with at least 0 - which it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a real answer - but if I change to 4.5 of .NET Framework, it works on other computers as well.